# How to sync two folders which are in two different systems

Tags: python, linux, synchronization, directory, watchdog

I would like to do a two-way automatic sync between folders Directory A and Directory B. This means that whenever a file in Directory A or one of its sub-directories is changed, that change is immediately applied to Directory B, and whenever a file in Directory B or one of its sub-directories is changed, that change is immediately applied to Directory A. Thus, the two directories would be completely identical, including document properties. How can I achieve this?

I m trying to this in python can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a simple link via `ln`?

Comment: @JohnMoon Actually i want to use this between two different systems

Comment: Ah, perhaps a misleading title then. :)

Comment: Look into `rsync` - sounds like a good bet for what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JohnMoon I want to develop on my own becoz its my project .. I am unable to come to conclusion when to delete a file from other directory and when to add a file in other directory.

Comment: Have you looked into the [filecmp](https://docs.python.org/3/library/filecmp.html) library? Note that it does not seem to compare recursively, but it is a good start.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/joshdick/pytograph) is a github entry that should take you halfway. Also see [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7317/keeping-remote-folders-in-sync-with-local-ones).

Comment: Also: your question is really broad. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is your question *exactly*?

Comment: @agtoever i have tried hashing of files and directory and if hash change occurs then i have overwrite/upload to remote server . But i unable to do that becoz storing old hash was difficult and also tried with watchdog but struct if a  file was deleted

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use autofs(and NFS) OR can write script in crontab by updae feature of rsync command (one in server A and one in server B) for move new files or sub directories